# <ReferenceArrayField> with complex arrays

Tags: react-admin

Based on this link: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/docs/Fields.md and the section that explains

My List component display the loading bar indefinitely and my suspicious is that my array is not a primitive array.

The sample uses this array:

```
{
    id: 1234,
    title: 'Lorem Ipsum',
    tag_ids: [1, 23, 4]
}
```

Mine uses:

```
{
    id: 1234,
    title: 'Lorem Ipsum',
    tag_ids: [
         {
         "id": "fa4aca34-b687-4b2e-987e-dae9db379807",
          "amount": 111.04
        }]
}
```

Is this a problem? of   does this support complex arrays?

This is how I call it within a list:

```
<List {...props} title="my title"         
        filters={<UserFilter />} 
        // actions={<PostActions />}
        >
        <Datagrid>

            <TextField source="street" label="Address"/>
            <TextField source="city" label="City"/>
            <BooleanField source="isBlocked" label="Blocked" />
            <TextField source="postcode" label="ZIP"/>            
            <EditButton />
            <ShowButton />

            <ReferenceArrayField label="Invoices" reference="invoices" source="invoices">
                <Datagrid>
                    <TextField source="id" />
                    <TextField source="invoiceNumber" />                    
                </Datagrid>

            </ReferenceArrayField>
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
```

I will appreciate any guidance in here in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the depreciated Admin-on-Rest. Please use the much improved [React-Admin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin).

[ArrayField](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#arrayfield) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Great yes that was the case. I had the impression that old version had a better documentation somehow.
So essentially on the new version we don't need to define the resource component in the App.js
Thanks for your prompt response.